# How to make WPF WrapPanel height automatically grow (double) when wrap to two lines occurs

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid with two rows like

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="44" />
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
  //...
</WrapPanel>
```

In the first row I am placing a WrapPanel with horizontal orientation. The elements within the WrapPanel are approx 40 heigth so it looks cool when there is only one line. However when the items wraps to two lines (say because the user decreases the width of the *column* with GridSplitter) then the WrapPanel correctly breaks into two line, but the second line is not shown, because the fixed 44 row height.

How can I achieve that the first row should be 44 or 88 according the WrapPanel's one line or two line layout?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know for sure, but the answer probably involves a converter.  Check them out here: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame I did not figured out... "Auto" is the answer. Auto is never worked for me so maybe that's why it was not popped up in my mind first....

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
```